# Flutter I can't build apk with build apk command

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety, flutter-build, flutter-apk

I build an app and trying to build apk. But the apk that I build with `flutter build apk` command is not working. There is a white screen coming. Today I connect my device with USB and I build it into my device in that way. This time it worked. What I have to do? What am I doing wrong? Is it can be cause of null safety or something else.

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889], locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (5 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\SEZEN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.31702.278
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

[√] VS Code (version 1.70.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\SEZEN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.46.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 104.0.5112.81
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 104.0.1293.54
    ! Device emulator-5554 is offline.

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are ava
```

ilable

Comment: In which system it doesn't work, what are the steps to reproduce that? Also, please update your Flutter version, and update the question with the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: In VSCode. I am making flutter clean, flutter run then flutter build apk after that Sending that release apk to me from whatsapp. I am uploading it. Then it comes the white screen. I edited the file.

Answer (score 0):

Run following command in your terminale and see error log in your console.

> flutter run --release